# How can add rightmost column by calculating all prices by id wise?

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables. they are as follows:

```
-- 1.   m_student
-- 2. t_reserve_a   
-- 3. t_reserve_b
-- 4.   t_reserve_c
```

I wanted to merge all required data from these 4 tables and get the total price of ordered textbooks in rightmost column as "total". i have tried to merge data from these table as follows:

```
SELECT tr.recptid AS ID, 
       tr.student_id AS S_ID,
       tr.student_name AS S_N,
       tr.student_zip AS ZIP,
       tr.student_address AS ADD1,
       tr.student_address2 AS ADD2,
       tr.student_tel AS TEL,
       IFNULL(tr.text_name, '') AS T_N,
       tr.price,
       COALESCE(tr.upd_date, rc.upd_date) AS UPDT
  FROM 
    ( SELECT ra.reserve_id,
       RIGHT(ra.reserve_id,5) AS recptid,
       m.student_id,
       m.student_name, 
       m.student_zip,
       m.student_address,
       m.student_address2, 
       m.student_tel, 
       rb.subject, 
       rb.text_name, 
       rb.price, 
       rb.upd_date
    FROM t_reserve_a AS ra INNER JOIN t_reserve_b AS rb ON ra.reserve_id=rb.reserve_id
    INNER JOIN m_student AS m ON m.student_id=ra.student_id ) AS tr
  LEFT JOIN t_reserve_c AS rc ON tr.reserve_id=rc.reserve_id
  ORDER BY tr.reserve_id
```

they display like here in below:

```
ID      S_ID       S_N  ZIP         ADD1    ADD2               TEL             T_N  price   UPDT
00000   19C2135004L H A 100-0000    USA     TUCSON AZ 85705     0000-00-0000    GA  2475    2020/04/13 8:04:36
00000   19C2135004L H A 100-0000    USA     TUCSON AZ 85705     0000-00-0000    R   1782    2020/04/13 8:04:36
00001   20A1109010F H S 100-0001    USA     TUCSON AZ 706       0000-00-0001    R   1782    2020/04/13 8:05:51
00001   20A1109010F H S 100-0001    USA     TUCSON AZ 706       0000-00-0001    LL  891     2020/04/13 8:05:51
00002   19C2134016F M K 100-0002    USA     PHOENIX AZ 85123    0000-00-0002    R   2475    2020/04/13 8:06:27
00003   20A1124018B C O 100-0003    USA     PHOENIX AZ 85122    0000-00-0003    LL  1782    2020/04/13 8:06:47
00003   20A1124018B C O 100-0003    USA     PHOENIX AZ 85122    0000-00-0003    R   891     2020/04/13 8:06:47
00004   20C2136005I F H 100-0004    USA     SEATTLE WA 98102    0000-00-0004    R   3534    2020/04/13 8:07:03
00004   20C2136005I F H 100-0004    USA     SEATTLE WA 98102    0000-00-0004    T   2178    2020/04/13 8:07:03
00004   20C2136005I F H 100-0004    USA     SEATTLE WA 98102    0000-00-0004    GB  4158    2020/04/13 8:07:03
00005   20C3156502C Y   100-0005    USA     TUCSON AZ 8572      0000-00-0005    R   3534    2020/04/13 8:07:58
00005   20C3156502C Y   100-0005    USA     TUCSON AZ 8572      0000-00-0005    GB  2178    2020/04/13 8:07:58
```

But how can I add total column like as below:

```
ID      S_ID       S_N  ZIP         ADD1    ADD2                  TEL           T_N price    UPDT              total
00000   19C2135004L H A 100-0000    USA     TUCSON AZ 85705     0000-00-0000    GA  2475    2020/04/13 8:04:36  4257
00000   19C2135004L H A 100-0000    USA     TUCSON AZ 85705     0000-00-0000    R   1782    2020/04/13 8:04:36  
00001   20A1109010F H S 100-0001    USA     TUCSON AZ 706       0000-00-0001    R   1782    2020/04/13 8:05:51  2673
00001   20A1109010F H S 100-0001    USA     TUCSON AZ 706       0000-00-0001    LL  891     2020/04/13 8:05:51  
00002   19C2134016F M K 100-0002    USA     PHOENIX AZ 85123    0000-00-0002    R   2475    2020/04/13 8:06:27  2475
00003   20A1124018B C O 100-0003    USA     PHOENIX AZ 85122    0000-00-0003    LL  1782    2020/04/13 8:06:47  2673
00003   20A1124018B C O 100-0003    USA     PHOENIX AZ 85122    0000-00-0003    R   891     2020/04/13 8:06:47  
00004   20C2136005I F H 100-0004    USA     SEATTLE WA 98102    0000-00-0004    R   3534    2020/04/13 8:07:03  9870
00004   20C2136005I F H 100-0004    USA     SEATTLE WA 98102    0000-00-0004    T   2178    2020/04/13 8:07:03  
00004   20C2136005I F H 100-0004    USA     SEATTLE WA 98102    0000-00-0004    GB  4158    2020/04/13 8:07:03  
00005   20C3156502C Y   100-0005    USA     TUCSON AZ 8572      0000-00-0005    R   3534    2020/04/13 8:07:58  5712
00005   20C3156502C Y   100-0005    USA     TUCSON AZ 8572      0000-00-0005    GB  2178    2020/04/13 8:07:58
```

can anyone please help me to sort out this problem?

Comment: Consider handling this in your presentation layer (e.g. PHP), rather than in MySQL.  Also, it is not acceptable for your sample data to be in external links alone, this data should be part of your question above.

Comment: thanks for advise. i did change accordingly... can you please help me to sort out this problem?